# Calling on variables outside of for loops?

Tags: java

Super new to coding so I am still pretty in the dark about a lot of concepts however, I have to create a program where the user can input a number to list a bunch of random words and then print a string of the first letter of every word at the end.

This is what I have so far:

```java
int N = IOTool.readIntFromTerminal("Enter amount of words: ");
for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
    String noun = WordTool.getRandomNoun();
    System.out.println("Word #" + i + " is " + noun);
    char first = noun.charAt(0);
    System.out.println(first);
}
System.out.println("All the first letters: " );
```

Output example:

```
Word #1 is pioneer
Word #2 is sunken
Word #3 is bedim
Word #4 is spill
Word #5 is step
Word #6 is shutdown
Word #7 is menace
Word #8 is grit
Word #9 is jelly
Word #10 is bifurcate
All the first letters: psbsssmgjb
```

Comment: Why use Scanner?  No indication was given that the "tools" being used were inadequate to this exercise.

Answer (score 5):

You have two problems to solve.

1. The variable 'first' is not available outside the loop.
2. The variable 'first' only ever has one value at a time (!), which is the value it got on the last pass through the loop.

For #1, you need to understand "scopes".  Very loosely speaking, in Java it means a variable does not exist outside the brace-pair it is declared within. The corollary is that you must declare the variable in a wide-enough scope so that it exists where you need it.

But because of #2, it's not going to help to just move the `char first` outside the loop.  You need a structure that can collect the first letters.  A String would do in this case.

Declare  `String firstLetters = ""` before the loop. Then in the loop:

```
char first = noun.charAt(0);
firstLetters += first;
```

The `+=` operator on a String appends the value from its right-hand side.

Then of course at the end you print firstLetters.

Comment: An alternative here is to use a `char[]` (with length `N`) to add each element at a time, and then transform it to a `String` using `new String(charArray)`.